# gnome-keyring-daemon memory problem

Tags: google-chrome, performance, memory-usage, gnome-keyring

**gnome-keyring-daemon uses enormous quantities of memory** when used **with google chrome** (seen on 14.0,4, 16.04 and 17.x, grows **up to 2 Gb**), hogging down whole system.

It seems that the problem is around quite a long, few examples here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/1094496

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1485439

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2266820

etc.

**Is there any possibility to correct this behavior or to replace gnome-keyring with anything less insane ?**

Comment: Its not a fix, but only workaround, you can restart daemon: gnome-keyring-daemon -r -d

Comment: The cited Launchpad bug was supposedly fixed in 2013. Are you sure it's the same?

Comment: @DavidFoerster Although bug was reported fixed in 2013 someone posted in 2015 near the bottom: `while true; do ssh localhost date; done` still eats up RAM.